# How to get the complete URL by making a google search with BS4 and Requests

Tags: url, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So, I was making a program that will search google and fetch all the results for a given keyword. I wanted to get all the URLs and print them out to the screen, and I decided to use BS4 for this and this is how I did it:

```
r = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={dork}&start={page}',headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
urls = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'BNeawe UPmit AP7Wnd'})
for url in urls:
url = url.split('<div class="BNeawe UPmit AP7Wnd">')[1].split('</div>')[0]
url = url.replace(' › ','/')
print(f'{Fore.GREEN}{url}{Fore.WHITE}')
open(f'results/{timeLol}/urls.txt', "a")
```

But, it did not return the complete URL instead, if the URL was big it returned `...` after some of the URL, is there any way at all to get the complete URL even if it is not using BS4 and Requests.

Answer (score 0):

Any search query example would be appreciated.

While you don't provide query example, you can try to use `bs4` [`css` selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) ([`css` selectors reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)):

```py
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']

# https://spicysouthernkitchen.com/best-way-to-cook-corn-on-the-cob/
# other URLs below...
```

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Scrape-Title-Link-Snippet-python#main.py) that scrapes more:

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {'q': 'how to cook best corn on the cob'}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

# container with all needed data
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(link)

---------
'''
https://spicysouthernkitchen.com/best-way-to-cook-corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/222352/jamies-sweet-and-easy-corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.delish.com/cooking/a22487458/corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.thekitchn.com/best-method-cook-corn-skills-showdown-23045869
https://natashaskitchen.com/15-minute-corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.thegunnysack.com/how-long-to-boil-corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/basic-method-for-cooking-corn-on-the-cob-40047
https://houseofnasheats.com/the-best-boiled-corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.tasteofhome.com/article/perfect-corn-on-the-cob/
'''
```

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using Google Search Results API from SerpApi, but without thinking about how to parse stuff since it's already done for the end user. All that needs to be done is just to iterate over structured JSON string.

It's a paid API with a free plan.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "how to cook best corn on the cob",
  "hl": "en",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
    link = result['link']
    print(link)

----------
'''
https://spicysouthernkitchen.com/best-way-to-cook-corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/222352/jamies-sweet-and-easy-corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.delish.com/cooking/a22487458/corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.thekitchn.com/best-method-cook-corn-skills-showdown-23045869
https://natashaskitchen.com/15-minute-corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.thegunnysack.com/how-long-to-boil-corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/basic-method-for-cooking-corn-on-the-cob-40047
https://houseofnasheats.com/the-best-boiled-corn-on-the-cob/
https://www.tasteofhome.com/article/perfect-corn-on-the-cob/
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.